# Show that the mapping defines a scalar multiplication

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

> We have the vector space $(\mathbb{R}^n,+, \cdot)$ over the field
>   $(\mathbb{R},+, \cdot)$. For any elements $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^n$ the
>   following mapping is defined:
>
> $$\left \langle x,y \right \rangle = x_1 \cdot y_1$$

I have checked this on the internet and it's saying that a mapping is called scalar multiple, if the conditions are satisfied:

1. $\left \langle x,y \right \rangle = \left \langle y,x \right \rangle \forall x,y \in \mathbb{R}^n$
2. $\left \langle x_1+x_2,y \right \rangle=\left \langle x_1,y \right \rangle+\left \langle x_2,y \right \rangle \forall x_1,x_2,y \in \mathbb{R}^n$
3. $\left \langle \lambda \cdot x,y \right \rangle= \lambda \cdot \left \langle x,y \right \rangle \forall x,y \in \mathbb{R}^n, \lambda \in \mathbb{R}$
4. $\left \langle x,x \right \rangle \geq 0 \forall x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $\left \langle x,x \right \rangle=0$ if and only if $x=0$

I used that and here is my solution:

1. is satisfied because $x \cdot y = y \cdot x$
2. is satisfied because $(x_1+x_2) \cdot y = (x_1 \cdot y)+(x_2 \cdot y)$
3. is satisfied because $\lambda \cdot x \cdot y = \lambda(x \cdot y)$
4. I don't know how this could be shown : /

Is it correctly at all what I did so far? If so, it seems like a very strange task... But I really don't know about the last condition of how it could be shown?

Comment: How is the product of two vectors $x\cdot y$ defined? You mean "scalar product", not scalar multiple.

Comment: I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The product indicated by $\cdot$ are different things in the two structures $(\mathbb{R}^n,+, \cdot)$ and $(\mathbb{R},+, \cdot)$ , and none of these can be used to define a ''product'' $\langle x,y\rangle$ as $x\cdot y$ because, $x$ and $y$ are elements of $\mathbb{R}^n$ so the product on  $(\mathbb{R},+, \cdot)$ cannot be applied to two vectors and the product on $(\mathbb{R}^n,+, \cdot)$ is defined between a scalar and a vector so also it cannot be used to ''multiply'' two vectors.

---

You have changed the answer and there is a bit of confusion on the notation.

I suppose that $x_1\cdot y_1$ in the definition of $\langle x,y\rangle$ refers to the first component of the vectors  $\vec x$ and $\vec y$. In this case  ,  your definition satisfies the first $3$ properties of an inner product.

For the property $4)$ note that $\langle \vec x, \vec x\rangle=x_1\cdot x_1=x_1^2\ge 0$ becuase $x_1$ is a real number and its square is positive, and is null if $x_1=0$, but the other components of $\vec x$ can be different from $0$, so the property $4)$ is not verified because we can have $\langle \vec x, \vec x\rangle =0$ for $\vec x \ne 0$.

Comment: Sorry I just have asked my teacher and there was a typo in the task, I just have editted it.

Answer (score 2):

If the product of two vectors $x\cdot y$ is defined as $(x_1,\dots,x_n)\cdot(y_1,\dots,y_n) = \sum_{j=1}^{n} x_jy_j$, then, for every $x=(x_1,\dots,x_n)\in\mathbb{R}^n$,
$$ x\cdot x = \sum_{j=1}^n x_j^2.$$
Since each $x_j\in\mathbb{R}$ we can conclude that $x_j^2 \geq 0$ and therefore $x\cdot x \geq 0$.

Besides, $x\cdot x = 0 \iff \sum_{j=1}^n x_j^2 = 0 \iff x_j^2 = 0 \iff x_j = 0 \iff x=0. $

**EDIT:**

Well, $\langle x, y\rangle = x_1y_1$ is not an inner product since $x=(0,1,\dots,1) \neq 0$ satisfies $\langle x, x\rangle = 0$.